# How can I click dropdown arrow, it will display all option not filter in mat-autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

I have a problem with mat-autocomplete.
I created a dropdown arrow within mat-autocomplete to show all options when I click it. When I click on it the first time, it shows all options

But when I choose 1 option and click again it just shows the options that are filtered by my choice option.

I just want it to show all the options when opening the dropdown. How can I resolve it?

My component.html

Comment: can you share your complete component.ts file please?

Comment: @RobRombouts Thanks for reply and help me to edit my question.. I updated my component.ts file. Please help me to resolve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by clearing your input when clicking on the arrow:

```
openAddDiag() { 
    this.myControl2.setValue(""):
};
```

but I don't know if this is the wanted behavior if it isn't it requires a more complex structure where you implement a custom search function.
Since you explicitly click on the arrow it is not a bad practice to empty the input as you have the intention to make changes (else you wouldn't click).

Comment: Thanks Rob..This way is good but my input flied will always clear when I click dropdown arrow. Do you have another way to show all options but not clear input value

Comment: you can set the current selected value as a placeholder. this way it still is visible.

Comment: Sorry Rob, But how can I do it.. I'm sorry I don't understand